# How to observe mousemoves with angular2 and angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have the following:

### angular2 (NameCmp)

```
import {
    OnInit, Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewChild, ElementRef,
    AfterViewInit
} from 'angular2/core'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

..
export class NameCmp implements AfterViewInit{
....
  @ViewChild('card')
  card: ElementRef;
  mouseMoves$: Observable<MouseEvent>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.mouseMoves$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.card.nativeElement, 'mousemove');

    this.mouseMoves$.subscribe( event => console.log('logging mousemove'));

  console.log('after view init')
}
```

### .html

```
...
<md-card #card>
  <md-card-content>
    <md-input
        required
        placeholder = "Title"
        [ngFormControl] = "titleCtrl"></md-input>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

However, although the `console.log('after view init')` prints to the console, the `console.log('logging mousemove'));` statement does not.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to import `fromEvent`

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent";
```

or import `Observable` from `Rx`

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WaDoBXBw1K8ugsiuIARc?p=preview)

**Update**
In order to get a reference of the nativeElement of the referenced component. e.g. get the nativeElement of the `md-card`, you need to pass the object `{read:ElementRef}` to `ViewChild()`

```
@ViewChild('card', {read: ElementRef})
```

[Check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5EgXVim2CMQo8cpulLBB?p=preview)

Comment: The `#card` is a material2-design card component. Making the change did not cause the cosole to print what I expected. Is a nativeElment only html elements, eg like div etc, excludes a component element? I see that your plunker works though.

Comment: I was correct. Assigning the #card to a <section> prints to the console like your plunker. Do you have any idea how to make this work on non-native elements?

Comment: @st_clair_clarke yes the `viewChild` binds to nativeElement only if it's not on a component/directive [check this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html). There should be a way to bind to the native template of the component. I will check the docs and let you know.

Comment: I will try the ViewChild as a directive. I think that should work. Have a look at this recent article [http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)

Comment: @st_clair_clarke I just updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Humm, neither plukr now works? Nothing is displayed with the mousemove.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke humm :D, they both work. I just tried them. And I updated the last plunker to show info on a div instead of the log [try it](http://plnkr.co/edit/5EgXVim2CMQo8cpulLBB?p=preview)